# iOS8 Custom Keyboard Extension - UILexicon

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-extension, uilexicon

I am working on an iOS 8 custom keyboard extension. In this, I need to use auto suggestion words from Apple like the native keyboard.

How can I achieve this by `UILexicon`? I am new to `UILexicon`.

Comment: please look at solution in 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26916783/840742