# Add a Language Lexicon to iOS Custom Keyboard for Predictive (Suggestive) Text

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, prediction, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm Trying to create a custom iOS keyboard. I used the *UILexicon* class to provide a basic lexicon of words that **requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion:** method provides.

But I want to add the **Predictive Text** to the keyboard as well.

I know that its not possible to create a database of words even if you try with full Effort.

So, I Believe that no one would have done it with their own keyboard. There must be a pre-Created ***Database*** of words and I know that.

Even if I find a ***Database*** of these words, I don't understand how to provide a ***Suggestion*** based on the ***Previous*** word.

> Could any one Point me to a good and trusted Source that could provide me the results I want and give me a database of the Lexicons of **English** as well as **Other Languages** too.
>
> Please even suggest the way to use the Database in the App.

### All Responses would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out the [UITextChecker class](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html) for implementing advanced auto-correct. It allows predictive suggestions based on what the user is typing but is not context aware. That coupled with [UILexicon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILexicon_Class/index.html) would be a pretty decent basic autocorrect.

You should also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627616/how-to-use-autocorrection-and-shortcut-list-in-ios8-custom-keyboard/26916783#26916783)

Comment: I tried the UITextChecker class for ***completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:***  method, Its mentioned that the objects in array it will return would be in sequence which should be used as they are. But the sequence is not appropriate.

And Can you suggest something about the Suggestions that we can implement for the next word based on the previous?

Comment: Predictive text would have to be built by you as Apple offers no API for that. I thought the sequence was appropriate are you sure?

Comment: The sequence comes in alphabetical order, not in the order of commonly used words in the language. When I read the documentation of UITextChecker class I first Imagined the ***completionsForPartialWordRange:inString:language:*** method would return the sequence in commonly used to rarely used words. It isn't the Case though.

Comment: Do you know any sqlite databases, or any other APIs? I found [LexiconText](http://www.lexicontext.com) API but I thought its not too good for this job.

Comment: unfortunately I don't

Comment: I did just just that with a custom iOS keyboard.  Using lexicon and UITextChecker class provides pretty the same functionality as the stock keyboard, except the context aware part.  That will need to be custom logic, I did not add that in my keyboard, but using TextChecker picks up on what word the user is typing very quickly.